# Implementing a Basic Google Place Add with Python

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, urllib2

I want to allow users to add places to Google Maps using my app. This tutorial shows how to implement a Place Search https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/basic-place-search I understand the code but Place Search and Place Add are different. In Place Add we have to use a POST URL and POST body https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?hl=fr#adding_a_place. I don't know how to insert POST body in my code. I want to use this code but to adapt it to Place Add:

```
import urllib2
import json

AUTH_KEY = 'Your API Key'

LOCATION = '37.787930,-122.4074990'

RADIUS = 5000

url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%s'
     '&radius=%s&sensor=false&key=%s') % (LOCATION, RADIUS, AUTH_KEY)

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

json_raw = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(json_raw)

if json_data[‘status’] == ‘OK’:
    for place in json_data['results']:
        print ‘%s: %s\n’ % (place['name'], place['reference'])'
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for your help @codegeek I finally find the solution based on this library https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key=%s' % AUTH_KEY
data = {
    "location": {
        "lat": 37.787930,
        "lng": -122.4074990
     },
     "accuracy": 50,
     "name": "Google Shoes!",
     "types": ["shoe_store"]
}
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json.dumps(data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
add_response = json.load(response)
if add_response['status'] != 'OK':
    # there is some error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the urllib2 documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2, it clearly states the following:

"urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])

> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
>   or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the
>   only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a
>   GET when the data parameter is provided. data should be a buffer in
>   the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The
>   urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples
>   and returns a string in this format"

So, you need to call the urlopen function with data parameter which will then send the request through POST. Also. looking through the Google Places Add API page, you need to prepare the data which includes location, accruracy etc. urlencode() it and you should be good.
If you want an example, see this gist at:
https://gist.github.com/1841962#file_http_post_httplib.py